# Restart static resources every spring boot restart

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle

Can someone tell me how to delete previous runtime operations on static Resources in Eclipse/Spring.

```
imageDir=new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\workspace\\uploadingFiles\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\images");
```

Every next run must reset all previous runs operations in my resources

I am using Gradle(STS).
Commands I used with my project(CMD Console):

```
gradlew wrapper
gradle build
gradlew bootrun //every time I use this command to run Spring Boot
taskkill /F /PID <PID_NUMBER> //command to stop application
```

Answer (score 1):

use Apache Commons IO.

```
FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit(new File("C:\\Users\\lukas\\workspace\\uploadingFiles\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\images"));
```

Schedules a file to be deleted when JVM exits.

reference:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: Some instructions How use it?